# Что сделать, чтобы не зависала?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Возникает часто проблема следующего характера.

Запускаю джобу. Но она подвисает по каким-то причинам. Например, в докере был запущен `serve and listening` специально или нет — не важно. Но мне хочется, чтобы после того, как я нажимаю "cancel" происходила остановка контейнера. Сейчас контейнер зависает в таком случае.

Я не отвечаю за поддержку гитлаба. Хотелось бы понять, потенциально такое возможно сделать и сложно ли. И почему может он может сейчас зависать? Я грешу на `shell-executor`.

Comment: Как заголовок вопроса связан с содержимым?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, проблема в `shell-executor`. Его следует заменить на `docker-executor` или [иной](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/), который позволяют запускать контейнеры изолированно.

Следует [отметить](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/1770), что контейнеру отправляется `SIGTERM` и через 10 минут `SIGKILL`.